# appcrash issue occurs when I launch the moodle 2.6.2 using xampp

Tags: php, apache, moodle, crash

I am using

`Moodle 2.6.2 (Build: 20140310), php 5.4.7, MySQL 5.5.27, Apache 2.4.3, XAMPP server version 1.8.1`.

I am able to load the page '`localhost/xampp`'.

When I try to launch '`localhost/moodle`' then it throws the following error

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: httpd.exe
Application Version: 2.4.3.0
Fault Module Name: php5ts.dll
Fault Module Version: 5.4.7.0
...
...
...
```

Anybody has suggestion to resolve this '`appcrash`' issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check the PHP and server log files to see if they give you a specific error message.